# NTLM over SOAP security

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, ntlm, exchangewebservices

I've come across this piece of code to access Exchange with PHP:

https://github.com/rileydutton/Exchange-Web-Services-for-PHP

It (among others) seems to use NTLM over SOAP as described here: http://www.howtoforge.com/talking-soap-with-exchange

I'm not familiar with SOAP. Are there security concerns with using this method? Is the data transmitted securely? Is supplying an SSL soap address in Services.wsdl enough?

```
<wsdl:service name="ExchangeServices">
    <wsdl:port name="ExchangeServicePort" binding="tns:ExchangeServiceBinding">
        <soap:address location="https://exchange.example.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Comment: Hi @SkyNT are you solved it? I'm developing a new service to do NTLM authentication https://www.nafiux.com/wasp/ if I can help you please let me know